# Too many data type queries on creating persistent manager with datanucleus

Tags: performance, jdbc, jdo

We found the performance of connecting to a remote postgres database is very bad with datanucleus and postgresql jdbc. The reason is there are many queries generated to query the data type table: pg_catalog.pg_type.

We wrote a small program as follows and added datanucleus, JDO & postgres jdbc jars to classpath, it will get every individual entry from pg_catalog.pg_type when creating the persistent manager.

Test program:

```
Map properties = new HashMap();
properties.put("javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass", "org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory");
properties.put("datanucleus.storeManagerType", "rdbms");
properties.put("datanucleus.ConnectionDriverName", "org.postgresql.Driver");
properties.put("datanucleus.ConnectionURL", "jdbc:postgresql://xxxx:5432/mydb");
properties.put("datanucleus.ConnectionUserName", "xxx");
properties.put("datanucleus.ConnectionPassword", "xxx");

properties.put("datanucleus.autoCreateSchema", "false");
properties.put("datanucleus.autoCreateTables", "false");
properties.put("datanucleus.autoCreateColumns", "false");
properties.put("datanucleus.autoCreateConstraints", "false");

properties.put("datanucleus.validateSchema", "false");
properties.put("datanucleus.validateTables", "false");
properties.put("datanucleus.validateConstraints", "false");
properties.put("datanucleus.validateColumns", "false");
properties.put("datanucleus.metadata.validate", "false");

PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(properties);
PersistenceManager pm = PersistenceManagerFactoryUtils.getPersistenceManager(pmf, true);
Query query = pm.newQuery("javax.jdo.query.SQL", "select * from dblanguage limit 10");
Object result = query.execute();
System.out.println("completed");
```

Here is part of executed queries we found in the database log file:

```
51 HKT LOG: execute <unnamed>: SELECT t.typlen FROM pg_catalog.pg_type t, pg_catalog.pg_namespace n WHERE t.typnamespace=n.oid AND t.typname='name' AND n.nspname='pg_catalog'
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT LOG: execute <unnamed>: SELECT t.typname,t.oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_type t JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON (t.typnamespace = n.oid) WHERE n.nspname != 'pg_toast'
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT LOG: execute <unnamed>: SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_type WHERE typname = $1 AND typinput='array_in'::regproc
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT DETAIL: parameters: $1 = 'int2vector'
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT LOG: execute <unnamed>: SELECT typname FROM pg_catalog.pg_type WHERE oid = $1
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT DETAIL: parameters: $1 = '22'
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT LOG: execute <unnamed>: SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_type WHERE typname = $1 AND typinput='array_in'::regproc
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT DETAIL: parameters: $1 = 'regproc'
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT LOG: execute <unnamed>: SELECT typname FROM pg_catalog.pg_type WHERE oid = $1
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT DETAIL: parameters: $1 = '24'
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT LOG: execute <unnamed>: SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_type WHERE typname = $1 AND typinput='array_in'::regproc
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT DETAIL: parameters: $1 = 'tid'
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT LOG: execute <unnamed>: SELECT typname FROM pg_catalog.pg_type WHERE oid = $1
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT DETAIL: parameters: $1 = '27'
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT LOG: execute <unnamed>: SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_type WHERE typname = $1 AND typinput='array_in'::regproc
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT DETAIL: parameters: $1 = 'xid'
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT LOG: execute <unnamed>: SELECT typname FROM pg_catalog.pg_type WHERE oid = $1
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT DETAIL: parameters: $1 = '28'
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT LOG: execute S_1: SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_type WHERE typname = $1 AND typinput='array_in'::regproc
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT DETAIL: parameters: $1 = 'cid'
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT LOG: execute S_2: SELECT typname FROM pg_catalog.pg_type WHERE oid = $1
2011-11-18 15:44:51 HKT DETAIL: parameters: $1 = '29'
......
```

Since there are too many (Thousands) such queries being executed, it will downgrade the performance. Anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

After I traced it further to the datanucleus library, here is the stacktrace showing how it calls to retrieve the data type info from rdbms:

```
RDBMSSchemaHandler.getRDBMSTypesInfo(Connection) line: 359  
RDBMSSchemaHandler.getSchemaData(Object, String, Object[]) line: 167    
PostgreSQLAdapter(DatabaseAdapter).initialiseTypes(StoreSchemaHandler, ManagedConnection) line: 462 
PostgreSQLAdapter.initialiseTypes(StoreSchemaHandler, ManagedConnection) line: 119  
RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(ClassLoaderResolver, OMFContext) line: 304 
NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Constructor, Object[]) line: not available [native method]   
NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]) line: not available 
DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]) line: not available 
Constructor<T>.newInstance(Object...) line: not available   
NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement, String, Class[], Object[]) line: 587   
PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(String, String, String, String, Class[], Object[]) line: 300    
FederationManager.initialiseStoreManager(ClassLoaderResolver) line: 173 
FederationManager.<init>(ClassLoaderResolver, OMFContext) line: 74  
JDOPersistenceManagerFactory(ObjectManagerFactoryImpl).initialiseStoreManager(ClassLoaderResolver) line: 139    
JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration() line: 583    
JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(Map) line: 286 
JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(Map) line: 182    
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: not available   
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: not available   
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: not available    
JDOHelper$16.run() line: 1958   
AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>) line: not available [native method] 
JDOHelper.invoke(Method, Object, Object[]) line: 1953   
JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(String, Map<?,?>, Map<?,?>, ClassLoader) line: 1159    
JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(Map<?,?>, Map<?,?>, ClassLoader) line: 803   
JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(Map<?,?>) line: 698  
PersistenceManagerFactoryTest.createPersistenceManagerFactory() line: 33    
PersistenceManagerFactoryTest.main(String[]) line: 86
```

Comment: And as you could easily determine, those queries aren't invoked by DataNucleus (which defines its queries in its log). Perhaps look at your JDBC driver ...

Comment: The stacktrace shows that DataNucleus gets the type info from database and caches it afterwards.

Comment: Conclusion : DataNucleus does *not* issue such calls. It simply calls DatabaseMetaData.getTypeInfo. The JDBC driver is the one issuing the SQL calls, and really ought to do a better job of providing which JDBC types are supported on this datastore. If you think you could provide a single SQL to provide the same info as getTypeInfo ought to provide then you could easily contribute it. I get no such performance issue with Postgresql 8+

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does it mean getting the type info is necessary for the JDBC? We don't have the performance problem if app server and db server are located in same place. When they'are located in different countries, such problem become obvious.

Comment: I am facing the same issue where PgDatabseMetaData.getTypeInfo class fetches 73,920 records and loops through each one of them. This is postgresql:42.2.5. For me it takes more than 20 minutes as the servers are in different location and database is huge.

Comment: This issue is with the older version of postgresql:42.2.5 and the query size for typeinfo reduces drastically when we use postgresql:42.3.3. This is maven dependency with groupId - org.postgresql